# How to resolve this type error in my Prolog code for generating the Collatz Sequence?

Tags: recursion, prolog, collatz

I am learning Prolog, specifically GNU Prolog, for fun. I thought an interesting challenge would be to generate a sequence of Collatz numbers given a seed, which here is 5. Here's my pseudocode:

```
collatz(curr, next) -> if even, next is curr / 2
collatz(curr, next) -> if odd, next is curr * 3 + 1

collatz_seq(1, [1]) -> terminate and return 1
collatz_seq(curr, [curr | accum]) -> next = collatz(curr), collatz_seq(next, accum)
```

I translated that to Prolog like this:

```
collatz(Curr, Next) :-
    0 is Curr mod 2,
    Next is Curr / 2.
collatz(Curr, Next) :-
    1 is Curr mod 2,
    Next is Curr * 3 + 1.

collatz_seq(1, [1]) :- !.
collatz_seq(Curr, [Curr | Accum]) :-
    collatz(Curr, Next),
    collatz_seq(Next, Accum).

% collatz_seq(3, X).
```

I first ran my code like this: `gprolog --consult-file collatz.pl` and tested out 3 with `collatz_seq(3, X).` in the REPL. `uncaught exception: error(type_error(integer,5.0),(is)/2)` was the REPL's response. I think that there's a problem here with 5 being misrepresented as 5.0. For 3 as input, the sequence should go 3 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1, but it terminates at 5. How do I avoid this intermingling of floats and ints when a float's decimal point is just zero?

Comment: Note: I just resolved this problem. `10 / 2` was yielding `5.0`, so I changed the operator to `//` and the problem went away.